# Can typescript infer that an argument has been validated?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, visual-studio-code

I'm still learning Typescript and Javascript so please excuse me if I am missing something.

The problem is as follows:

Currently VSCode does not infer that I throw an error if email is undefined when calling **this.defined(email)**. This is due to *validateEmail()* accepting a *string?* and will not compile because it thinks it could still receive an undefined value (is my deduction at least). Is there a way to tell the compiler this is ok? or am I missing something?

I would like to call Validate.validateEmail() from other classes and the problem arises in those classes as well.

#### Validate.ts

```
export default class Validate {
    static validateEmail(email?: string) {
        // TODO: Test this regex properly.
        const emailRegex = new RegExp('^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')

        this.defined(email);
        this.notEmpty(email);

        if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
            throw new SyntaxError("The email entered is not valid");
        }
    }

    static defined(text?: string) {
        if (!text) {
            throw new SyntaxError("The text recieved was not defined.");
        }
    }

    static notEmpty(text: string) {
        if (text.length < 1) {
            throw new SyntaxError("The text entered is empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws the error in ts?

Comment: this.notEmpty(email);

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). The type guard asserts the type of a particular variable like this:

```
export default class Validate {
  public static validateEmail(email?: string) {
    const emailRegex = new RegExp(
      '^(([^<>()[]\\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$'
    );

    if (!Validate.defined(email)) {
      throw new SyntaxError('The text recieved was not defined.');
    }

    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
      throw new SyntaxError('The email entered is not valid');
    }
  }

  public static defined(text?: string): text is string {
    return !!text;
  }

  public static notEmpty(text: string) {
    if (text.length < 1) {
      throw new SyntaxError('The text entered is empty.');
    }
  }
}
```

The downside is that you still need an if statement and the throw expression is outside of the function.

Or you can do something like this, which avoids those problems, but requires you to reassign `email` to the result of the function.

```
export default class Validate {
  public static validateEmail(email?: string) {
    const emailRegex = new RegExp(
      '^(([^<>()[]\\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$'
    );

    email = Validate.defined(email);

    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
      throw new SyntaxError('The email entered is not valid');
    }
  }

  public static defined(text?: string): string {
    if (!text) {
      throw new SyntaxError('The text recieved was not defined.');
    }
    return text;
  }

  public static notEmpty(text: string) {
    if (text.length < 1) {
      throw new SyntaxError('The text entered is empty.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch :)

Comment: Sometimes it's about typing fast. :)

Comment: The second answer seems to fit my needs in this specific instance. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can sometimes recognize that a variable is of a type narrower than its annotated or inferred type at certain points in the code, by [analyzing the control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis).  In the following code block, the compiler understands that `email` cannot be `undefined` if the flow of control reaches the `this.notEmpty()` call, and thus there is no error:

```
if (!email) {
    throw new SyntaxError("The text received was not defined.");
}

this.notEmpty(email); // okay
```

---

As you've discovered, though, simply refactoring the code to make the check happen in a different function does not work.  The compiler generally does not follow control flow into functions and methods when performing control flow analysis.  This is a [tradeoff (see Microsoft/TypeScript#9998 in GitHub for more info)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998): it's not feasible for the compiler to simulate the program running on all possible inputs, by analyzing the possible control flow paths through all possible function calls, so it has to use a heuristic somewhere; in this case, the heuristic is generally "assume function calls have no impact on variable types".  Therefore the call to `this.defined(email)` has no impact on the type of `email` as seen by the compiler, and thus it complains about `this.notEmpty(email)`.

---

Luckily, [TypeScript 3.7 introduced "assertion functions"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions); you can give a function a special *return type* that tells the compiler that a variable passed to the function will be narrowed by the function, and it will use this as part of its control flow analysis.  While the compiler doesn't infer such function signatures itself, at least now you can manually annotate that `defined()` asserts something about its argument:

```
static defined(text?: string): asserts text {
    if (!text) {
        throw new SyntaxError("The text recieved was not defined.");
    }
}
```

The return type of `defined()` is `asserts text`, which means that `text` will be verified as truthy if `defined()` returns.  And this fixes your original example:

```
this.defined(email);
this.notEmpty(email); // okay now!
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAaqpgJYKozBwDeAsAFBxtwEw0U5wBu5KjWABRALaoKmABTAJUgPwAuDjCgUAdgHMAlAxbtDcAPTG4AFQDyAEUsrzwTnBgALCsSjAtoOGCgQwYChMAE8AOjgDIzYcCA0nOUlMACUvHwBeOA1gAHc4VK0RcGkAcgA9aWkAbTKAHgA+aR0AHSrmgF1m5rCAGgBuJWaCAAEAInaAamlumoam1o6u3oGhscmdACodAB9pUbCJ0Z0dYcrWqoAGAFoATnb6AEYegGYAXxnru8eX97DL2-uTzeHwB3ze7R2lSqqCuAC8AIJXABazSun0m3R0E2hcMRSPuACYeq9jgASEo6FhU1jRZxuAhhJDITTABCyeSYHR9KLRVzuMIaCAwcRgGAhdlJLkmMwQADWqBCWQgOQAhNTaXAKMg4NIVYkpAVQGFaJwJVJjvoaRq2K5-HlsnkAMohDRcEAiKD+KB7cwuOj6zBwYCuoKszXEQXwASUBBHblWoyvHlwJPMZOcbi8Jkstm0EAwZSqdTaHQqQgEIIwYh5+BMBOGLU6lU1vR163sW3KrK5ODO12od2e6A+v3OUDwTw4CjAPhhnKEJXwbPZBBhOPJwypzfq9gZmA8RcisXSGsqTjF3SWjWNk-jsKYYNaVxwWpwB6tje0zv2nt9t0er0RzoGsgxDTwEHDIMxFFcJ13rdgtwQlhXiAA)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not compiling is because notEmpty needs to accept a nullable string. That is because at the call site you are passing a nullable string as an argument.The following code fixes the problems with your code.

```
export default class Validate {
    static validateEmail(email?: string) {
        // TODO: Test this regex properly.
        const emailRegex = new RegExp('^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')

        this.defined(email);
        this.notEmpty(email);

        if (email && !emailRegex.test(email)) {
            throw new SyntaxError("The email entered is not valid");
        }
    }

    static defined(text?: string) {
        if (!text) {
            throw new SyntaxError("The text recieved was not defined.");
        }
    }

    static notEmpty(text?: string) {
        if (text && text.length < 1) {
            throw new SyntaxError("The text entered is empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: His goal was to skip checking undefined in `notEmpty` because he already called the `defined` method previously.  This fixes the compilation but doesn't solve `thinks it could still receive an undefined value`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips It is best to create one method that does both the checks; undefined and not empty checks. I don't think tools are smart enough (as yet) to detect that the methods are called in a sequence and  notEmpty can't receive an undefined value. What if at a different spot in the code, notEmpty() is used without a preceding call to defined()?